# evaluate metrics during training with Estimator Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to print the R squared in addition of the loss during training. But I do not manage to get it. I did the following implementation:

UPDATE:

```
def r_squared_fn(labels, predictions, mode):
    if mode == learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
        return None
    else:
        SST, update_op1 = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, tf.reduce_mean(labels))
        SSE, update_op2 = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
        with tf.control_dependencies([update_op1,update_op2]):
            return tf.subtract(1.0, tf.div(SSE, SST), name = 'r'), tf.group(update_op1, update_op2)

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    predict = prediction()
    loss = model_loss()
    r_squared,_ = r_squared_fn(labels, predict, mode)

    train_op = model_train_op(loss, mode)

    predictions = {"predictions": predict}

    training_hooks = [
        tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
            tensors = {'training loss': loss,'training r_squared': r_squared})
    ]

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode = mode,
        predictions = predictions,
        loss = loss,
        train_op = train_op,
        training_hooks = training_hooks,
    )
```

Comment: Looks like that error is because the second return value of r_squared_fn is an Operation rather than a Tensor. Otherwise SST is probably 0 when the "r_squared,_" line gives you NaNs. May be just add a small constant to SST (e.g. `tf.div(SSE, SST + 1e-4)`)?

Comment: The SST cannot be zero though as my 'labels' are not constant equal to the mean. No other idea?

Comment: Oh, it's a metric. You probably just need to run the update op before you evaluate the metric's value (they use local variables under the hood).

Comment: You can do that with a [control dependency](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies) of the r_squared value on its update op to do it all in one go (but keep in mind that the metric's streaming values will be updated every time it gets logged).

Comment: You are probably right, but I'm trying to add : 'with tf.Graph().control_dependencies([update_op1,update_op2]):' before the return statement in my r_squared_fn function, and I have the error: 'Tensor Tensor("eval_metrics/mean_squared_error/update_op:0", shape=(), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.' Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Also tried 'test=r_squared_fn(labels, predict, mode, params)
    with tf.Graph().control_dependencies(test[1]):
        r_squared = test[0]' in my model_fn, but I have 'TypeError: 'Operation' object is not iterable'

Comment: And tried : 'with tf.Session().as_default() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        R_squared,opt = r_squared_fn(labels, predict, mode, params)
        with tf.Graph().control_dependencies([opt]):
            r_squared = R_squared.eval()', error: 'ValueError: Operation name: "group_deps"
op: "NoOp"
input: "^mean_squared_error_1/update_op"
input: "^mean_squared_error_2/update_op"
 is not an element of this graph.'

Comment: `tf.Graph()` constructs a new graph. I'd just use `with tf.control_dependencies([update_op1,update_op2]):`, which will use the default graph.

Comment: It works but the first iteration, whether it is the very first iteration or when I stop the training and resume it, the first iteration gives nan and then only it is calclated correctly..

Comment: Maybe a longshot, but try wrapping the metrics in a [tf.variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) with `use_resource=True`? If the metric uses resource variables, the reads from them should be affected by the control dependencies, which should fetch their updated values...

Comment: in the r_squared_fn I tried : with tf.variable_scope('test_var', use_resource=True):
            SST, update_op1 = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, tf.reduce_mean(labels))
        SSE, update_op2 = tf.metrics.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions)
and then the rest of the code but same, the first iteration gives 'INFO:tensorflow:step = 11, training loss = 1.21973, training r_squared = nan'. I stop at step 10 and resumed.

Comment: In addition, the results from the r_squared are weird. When retrieve the predictions and calculate myself the r_squared it is way smaller than that given by the metric during training (I am comparing on the same set obviously). So something is not correct there, but cannot figure out what..

Comment: Stepping back slightly, using metrics with the logging hook is a bit of a square peg in a round hole, and aggregating across training steps is somewhat odd anyway. Can you just run a periodic evaluation with the metrics, or log something that isn't a metric then plot it with smoothing in TensorBoard?

Comment: That's what I did at the beginning and it runs fine for evaluation. In the model_fn I have: 'eval_metric_ops = eval_metric_fn(labels, predictions, mode)' and then I returned tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,
        predictions,
        loss,
        train_op,
        eval_metric_ops). But I would like to see the r_squared on the training set as well...